# Combining 2 CTEs with Multiple Selects into One Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble trying to combine these two CTEs into one query. Can anyone help lead me in the right direction? I tried using comma after the first CTE and removing the 'WITH" in the second CTE, but not sure where to put the parentheses and getting an error:

> "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'SELECT'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 48 Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'."

```
  WITH ATQInfant_CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATQInfant_IndividualID ORDER BY ATQInfant_Date) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID,
        A1.ATQInfant_Date,
        A1.InfantSum,
        A2.InfantSum,
        CASE 
           WHEN 
A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum and
not exists(select 1 from ATQInfant_CTE A3 where A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A3.ATQInfant_IndividualID and A1.ATQInfant_Date < A3.ATQInfant_Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
    FROM
        ATQInfant_CTE AS A1

    INNER JOIN
        ATQInfant_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A2.ATQInfant_IndividualID 
                            AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
),

ANS_CTE AS 
    (   SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ANS_IndividualID ORDER BY ANS_SubmitDate) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptANSImprove]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ANS_IndividualID,
        A1.ANS_SubmitDate,
        A1.ANS_ArrSum,
        A2.ANS_DepSum,
        CASE 
           WHEN 
A1.ANS_ArrSum > A2.ANS_DepSum and
not exists(select 1 from ANS_CTE A3 where A1.ANS_IndividualID = A3.ANS_IndividualID and A1.ANS_SubmitDate < A3.ANS_SubmitDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
    FROM
        ANS_CTE AS A1
    INNER JOIN
        ANS_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ANS_IndividualID = A2.ANS_IndividualID 
                            AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
)
```

SAMPLE DATA:
[image]

[image]

Comment: add a semi column before the first: ;with. And after the secund cte copy select * from ANS_CTE

Comment: *"add a semi column before the first: ;with."*, it's not `;WITH` @zip. Just `WITH` is correct. the `;` goes at the **end** of statements, not the start.

Comment: I see, though you had some code before Dee that you didn't show us, my bad

Comment: I'm still getting **Recursive member of a common table expression 'ANS_CTE' has multiple recursive references.**  What do I do at the end of the 2nd CTE regarding select * from ANS_CTE?

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish? Please include sample data and desired results. This is an incomplete SQL query. There must be a final statement after CTEs are defined.

Comment: I'm attempting to get the queries to run. I'm not sure how to do the final statement.I tried 'select * from ANS_CTE' and the end but it gives me a recursive reference error.

Comment: I added sample data. I need the results of the data from the two queries

Comment: How do you want to combine the two resultsets? Separately, appended, merged?

Comment: I guess I want them merged, but also if the same IndividualID is in both queries I only want it to show in my results one time. The end result needs to have Flag = 1 when the A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum OR A1.ANS_ArrSum > A2.ANS_DepSum otherwise the Flag = 0

Comment: But what if there are multiple flags per IndividualID. Do you need to sum flags at individual ID level?

Comment: This part of the query prevents multiple Flag =1 per IndividualID, **not exists(select 1 from ATQInfant_CTE A3 where A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A3.ATQInfant_IndividualID and A1.ATQInfant_Date < A3.ATQInfant_Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0**  Yes I need to have Flag = 1 per IndividualID if it meets the criteria of my case statements but not more the 1 per IndividualID.

Comment: Normally I would just have CTEs separate, but since the same INdividualID could have Flag = 1 for ANS_CTE and another for ATQInfant_CTE I have to combine them so that I dont get a total of 2 for the Flag for each IndividualID

Comment: The code you posted works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC - Consider breaking up the `ROW_NUMBER` queries into their separate CTE, then run `SELECT DISTINCT` as final statement. Right now, you call the very CTE inside itself causing recursion which does not appear to be what you need. Below breaks up the two result sets:

```
-- First Query

WITH ATQInfant_CTE AS 
    (SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATQInfant_IndividualID 
                               ORDER BY ATQInfant_Date) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
    )

SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID,
        A1.ATQInfant_Date,
        A1.InfantSum AS A1_InfantSum,
        A2.InfantSum AS A2_InfantSum,
        CASE 
           WHEN A1.InfantSum > A2.InfantSum AND
                AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ATQInfant_CTE A3 
                               WHERE A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A3.ATQInfant_IndividualID 
                                 AND A1.ATQInfant_Date < A3.ATQInfant_Date) 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
FROM
   ATQInfant_CTE AS A1    
INNER JOIN
   ATQInfant_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ATQInfant_IndividualID = A2.ATQInfant_IndividualID 
                       AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1

-- Second Query

;WITH ANS_CTE AS 
      (SELECT
             *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ANS_IndividualID 
                                ORDER BY ANS_SubmitDate) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptANSImprove]
     )

SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ANS_IndividualID,
        A1.ANS_SubmitDate,
        A1.ANS_ArrSum,
        A2.ANS_DepSum,
        CASE 
           WHEN A1.ANS_ArrSum > A2.ANS_DepSum  
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ANS_CTE A3
                                WHERE A1.ANS_IndividualID = A3.ANS_IndividualID 
                                  AND A1.ANS_SubmitDate < A3.ANS_SubmitDate) 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
FROM
   ANS_CTE AS A1
INNER JOIN
   ANS_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ANS_IndividualID = A2.ANS_IndividualID 
                 AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
```

Should you need to merge aggregated results, place all four in separate CTEs:

```
WITH ATQInfant_CTE AS 
    (SELECT ...same as above...),

     ATQ_Final AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ...same as above...),

     ANS_CTE AS 
    (SELECT ...same as above...),

     ANS_Final AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ...same as above...)

-- MERGE/JOIN OF AGGREGATIONS
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT IndividualID, 
          SUM(A1_InfantSum) As Sum_A2_InfantSum,
          SUM(A2_InfantSum) As Sum_A2_InfantSum,
          SUM(Flag) AS Sum_ATQ_Flags
   FROM ATQ_Final
   GROUP BY IndividualID) agg1
FULL JOIN
  (SELECT IndividualID, 
          SUM(ANS_ArrSum) As Sum_ANS_ArrSum,
          SUM(ANS_DepSum) As Sum_ANS_ArrSum,
          SUM(Flag) AS Sum_ANS_Flags
   FROM ANS_Final
   GROUP BY IndividualID) agg2
ON sub1.IndividualID = sub2.IndividualID
```

Even add aggregates as two more CTEs!

```
WITH ATQInfant_CTE AS 
    (SELECT ...same as above...),

     ATQ_Final AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ...same as above...),

     ANS_CTE AS 
    (SELECT ...same as above...),

     ANS_Final AS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ...same as above...),

     ATQ_Agg AS 
    (SELECT IndividualID, 
            SUM(A1_InfantSum) As Sum_A2_InfantSum,
            SUM(A2_InfantSum) As Sum_A2_InfantSum,
            SUM(Flag) AS Sum_ATQ_Flags
     FROM ATQ_Final
     GROUP BY IndividualID),

     ANS_Agg AS 
    (SELECT IndividualID, 
            SUM(ANS_ArrSum) As Sum_ANS_ArrSum,
            SUM(ANS_DepSum) As Sum_ANS_ArrSum,
            SUM(Flag) AS Sum_ANS_Flags
     FROM ANS_Final
     GROUP BY IndividualID)

-- MERGE/JOIN OF AGGREGATIONS
SELECT *
FROM ATQ_Agg
FULL JOIN ANS_Agg
  ON ATQ_Agg.IndividualID = ANS_Agg.IndividualID
```